# Use Regex to make separate lists

Tags: python, regex, list

Let's say we've 6 files:

```
scTest_model1.zip
scTest_model2.zip
scTest_unfiltred_model1.zip
scTest_unfiltred_model2.zip
scStr_model1.zip
scStr_model2.zip
```

I need optimised regex to create 3 separate lists:

1. Filtered :

```
scTest_model1.zip
scTest_model2.zip
```

2. Unfiltered:

```
scTest_unfiltred_model1.zip
scTest_unfiltred_model2.zip
```

3. STR:

```
scStr_model1.zip
scStr_model2.zip
```

What's the most optimised regex I can use here? Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: What have you tried? What's your "unoptimised" version? Why does it need to be optimised?

Answer (score -1):

[link](https://regex101.com/r/yWCQgb/1) to regex description

```py
import re

s = """scTest_model1.zip
scTest_model2.zip
scTest_unfiltred_model1.zip
scTest_unfiltred_model2.zip
scStr_model1.zip
scStr_model2.zip"""

filtered = re.findall(r'(scTest_model\d+\.zip)', s, re.MULTILINE)
unfiltered = re.findall(r'(scTest_unfiltred_model\d+\.zip)', s, re.MULTILINE)
str_ = re.findall(r'(scStr_model\d+.zip)', s, re.MULTILINE)

print(filtered, unfiltered, str_)
```